# Maintain background image responsiveness regardless of screen size

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am currently developing a single page application using CRA.  I am attempting to create a hero image that lives at the top of the application and contains an overlay. For the hero image, I am using a background image. The issue I am running into is maintaining the overall responsiveness of the background image.  I would like the user to be able to see the entire background image regardless of the screen size.

the following link shows the effect I am attempting to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfzWLbAbcCw&feature=youtu.be

My JSX code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="container-background"> </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center", paddingTop: 20 }}>Welcome</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

My CSS code is as follows:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .container-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/iyFtMNA.jpg');
  opacity: .2;
  height: 1200px;
}
.container .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I am having a lot of difficulty on what css properties I can utilize to achieve my desired effect.  any and all suggestions are welcome!

The following link https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wozniak-t8wmx?file=/src/styles.scss:0-391
contains a sandbox for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for codeboxsandbox
I would it implement as so

react

```
   <div className="container">
      <div className="hero">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iyFtMNA.jpg" alt="bg" />
        <div className="overlay">
          <h1 className="title">Title</h1>
          <h2 className="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", paddingTop: 20 }}>Welcome</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.hero {
  position: relative;
}
.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .2;
}
.hero .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container .content {
  position: relative;
}
```

[bg-overlay-example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bg-overlay-example-sw97d?file=/src/styles.scss)

Comment: @RobertTerrell Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to set Different image for responsive version or you can use `background-size: 100% auto;` to see entire image but you need to decrease the height of that `div`

Comment: decrease the? do you mean the overall height of the div and as the screen gets smaller use a different sized image

Comment: 100% auto seems work, the only issue now I'm running into is that I can no longer control the overall height of the image by changing the divs height

Comment: could you possibly fork my code sandbox and show me an example of how you would go about this

Comment: or else you can change the image size in editor based on your common resolution, that should be easier for you . And after then for responsive you can use ```@media``` queries for to set responsive

Comment: if at all possible could you show me via the code sandbox link i attached?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wozniak-t8wmx?file=/src/styles.scss:0-391

Comment: @RobertTerrell 
for image resize you need change or resize image in any photo editor tool, or to set in all  resolution you need to just give```background-size: 100% auto;``` and give height based on resolution so it will not take too much space , but you can't use larger height for this type of background image. if you want use larger height of the background image then you need to make new image for that